# I keep getting "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present" even though I am sure a record exist

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I have been trying to figure out why I am getting this error message and it's driving me up the wall cause I think I have applied all that is needed to get the result I desire. What can I do to accomplish this.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Receive user input from login screen
            string username = txtUsername.Text;
            string password = txtPassword.Text;

            // Test if user input is null or white space aka empty
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter both username and password");
            else
            {
                // Establish connection with database
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"SERVER=KACY-PC\SQLEXPRESS2014;DATABASE=hardwareMgmt;Integrated Security=True");
                cn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = cn;

                string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "'";
                cmd.CommandText = strSQL;

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                // Count number of record
                int count = 0;
                while (dr.Read())
                    count += 1; MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(count));
                dr.Read();

                // Validate whether user has logged in before and display appropriate 
                if (count == 1 && dr["first_login"].ToString() == "N")
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome back '" + dr["first_name"].ToString() + "' '" + dr["last_name"].ToString() + "'", "Welcome back", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                else if (count == 1 && dr["first_login"].ToString() == "Y")
                    MessageBox.Show("Hello " + dr["first_name"].ToString() + "' '" + dr["last_name"].ToString() +
                        "\nIt appears that you are logging in for the first time" +
                        "\nor your password got reset", "Welcome", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                else if (count > 1)
                    MessageBox.Show("Duplication in user account \nPlease contact System Administrator", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I Keep getting the following result after I enter the credentials in the login window. I am sure that the record is found in the database but it just not reading it.

[image: This is the error message I am getting after I login]

Comment: Yes I'm sure it returns data. I have checked the database and even printed out the record count as stated in the code above. Additionally, I am just doing this for a school assignment that is due tomorrow. But sure, I would also like to know what you have in mind to mitigate against SQL Injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
dr.Read();
```

line is unnecessary since after your

```
while (dr.Read())
    count += 1; MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(count));
```

code, there will be *no* next record to read, that's why you get this error.

As Ivan commented, you can not read any data after your `while`. That's why, whatever wanna read `first_login`, `first_name`, `last_name` etc.. columns, you have to read while you iterating your reader. That's why consider to change your logic first.

And for myself, I prefer to use [`GetXXX` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_methods.aspx) of `SqlDataReader` when I wanna read the values instead of `dr[...]` syntax. That makes more readable in my opinion.

A few things more;

- You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
- Do not store your passwords as a plain text. Read: [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)
- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection, command and reader automatically.

Comment: +1 Just for the record, removing the unnecessary line would not  help because he'll start getting another exceptions of `dr[..]` statements. The whole logic is wrong.

Comment: @IvanStoev Right. I updated my answer based on your comment. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks this really helped. I must first say that I didn't get teaching at all in class. I have applied all of the above. `parameterized query`, `using statements` and re worked the logic so that the needed fields are captured during the `while (dr.read())`. The only thing I have not applied is not storing the password in the database as plain text. The reason is because its not really a requirement for this school assignment.

Comment: also I didn't employ the GetXXX methods of SqlDataReader because I didn't really understand how apply the concept.